# How to dynamically filter blog/list layout by today's date?

Tags: articles, custom-field, content-filtering

I've created a Joomla article category 'Events' with three list views:

1. all events
2. past events
3. future events

All three views refer to the same "Events" category. The past and future events layout use Joomla's filter ability, but that filter is currently not dynamic. When I select before respectively after "today" that date is hardcoded into the filter -- not very practical.

How can I dynamically filter the blog/list layout by today's date?

Comment: If is for events, I'd suggest using a proper events component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look to http://easylayouts.net/ function ? It offer filtering and ordering. We use it from month and it's quite usefull. I don't have check if it can filter on a "dynamic" value. If this fonction is not here maybe the team could add this.

Comment: Could you please clarify the wording in your last sentence and try to eliminate typos and grammatical errors to the best of your ability?